# Running a script from autostart results in poor performance

Tags: bash, debian, raspbian, lxde, autostart

I have a bash script to show an FFplay stream of a usb webcam and that script is set to run on start as a .desktop file. The only problem is that when it is run this way I'm getting terrible performance. I'll get less than 1 fps when running this way and I'll get 60 fps when running the script manually. Here is my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Webcam
Exec=/home/pi/autorun.sh
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a delay so that your desktop is fully loaded before the bulk of your script runs.

Comment: Instead of a delay I'd recommend making this a service, and making that service depend on the relevant other services.

Comment: @ajgringo619 So I made a script that sleeps for five minutes and then autoruns the script for FFplay. Even when sleeping for 5 minutes after boot the same thing happens.

Comment: @l0b0 I actually had a service for launching the script when usb was plugged in but removed it due to this same thing happening. It wasn't on boot either. Essentially I had the udev rule call the service which would then call the script and FFplay would run. I took the service out of the equation and launched the script directly with udev and it worked fine. Just need it to work fine on boot now.